# X minutes and Y seconds ago

Tags: android

I have made this line of code:

```
 (DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), seconds, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_TIME)).toString();
```

When 3 seconds have passed it returns:

```
3 seconds ago
```

When 125 seconds have passed it returns:

```
2 minutes ago
```

Is possible to change this code to return:

```
2 minutes and 5 seconds ago
```

Instead of 2 minutes ago? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %d min: %d sec ago",
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
                                          TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)))
```

which retruns the time in format like for eg **`2 min : 15 sec ago`**
where `millis` is the time in millisecond

**EDIT:** for days and hours

```
  int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(millis);
  long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(millis) - (day * 24);
  long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(millis) * 60);
  long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(millis) * 60);

  String time = String.valueOf(day) + " Days " + String.valueOf(hours) + " Hours " +
          String.valueOf(minutes) + " Minutes " + String.valueOf(seconds) + " Seconds.";
```

This way you can get days and even years..

Comment: yes.. its just a sample to show you.. you can also make `days` `hours`.. @tomss. Let me know if you need the code

Comment: @tomss if you get the no of days.. you can easily set the `week` property..

Comment: if you don't want to display the `0` value in any of the field.. you can convert individually and check value greater than 0. @tomss